# When should we say 'Thanks' and when, 'Thank you'?

Tags: formality, politeness, expression-choice, speech, register

While I'm communicating with my colleagues and clients, I used to say 'Thanks' and 'Thank you'. I normally use 'Thank you' when I want to express it to a single person usually through e-mails, otherwise I use 'Thanks' generally.

To improve my communication methods, I just want to know explicitly when I should use 'Thank you' and when, 'Thanks'.

Or, which is better professionally?

Comment: This is more a matter of register and formality than it is of anything else. There are no explicit “rules” here, so no one can give you an exact answer, just personal opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting point . Actually they are bit different though they are used to express gratitude.

1) "I thank you " is a full sentence with subject, verb and complement.
2)  "thanks" is a noun.

They have become sort of synonym,  tough "thanks" is also used to express gratitude and appreciations in more formal writing or speech such as: We want to express our thanks to those who helped us. Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I would say as a general rule that, in formal or business contexts, "thank you" is the way to go. "Thanks" can come as a little colloquial in comparison. If you want to avoid the awkwardness of using "thank you" to thank more than just one person ("you"), you could always use "thank you all [for your time/for your business/etc]."